# Why am I not receiving an EXDATE for a recurring event that has one of its instances removed or modified?

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, icalendar, google-api-php-client, rfc2445

Using the Google Calendar API, and for a weekly recurring event on every Friday that never ends, I have cancelled one of the instances and modified the starting time for another instance several weeks later. On fetching this event from the calendar, it does not contain any EXDATE as specified on http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445, referenced by https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts

Why not? How does Google handle the modification of instances within a recurring rule? In fact, I only ever see RRULE in the recurrence field of the response. When do the other types of recurrence types appear such as EXDATE, EXRULE, RDATE, etc..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will get an instance of a recurring event with status=CANCELLED instead of an EXDATE if you cancel the instance through the Calendar API. EXDATEs however are an alternative that results in the same effect of the event being deleted.
EXRULEs are now deprecated as per RFC 5545 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545), RDATEs should work.

Comment: If I cancel the instance through the Google Calendar UI but do not yet have a registered push notification channel for that calendar and then sync to the calendar by pulling all events, will there also be an instance with status=CANCELLED? I'm not seeing any instances of the recurrence with that status in the response...

Comment: Yes, CANCELLED instances will be in the response. I propose you try it out in the api explorer https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/

Comment: I see some cancelled instances in that response, but for different recurring events. The one I'm working on does not have any, yet I've cancelled a few instances from it.

Comment: Do they happen to be outside the time range you are specifying?

Comment: No, this recurring event was not outside the time range. I don't know what the problem was with that one, but all the rest I've tested seem to be working fine and sending the CANCELLED instance in the response. Thanks for your help.